# HelperList status action with ajax

Tags: php, ajax, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm in charge of creating a small payment module. The configuration has to be managed with a simple CRUD, and I use the HelperList class to display a table with the records stored in the database.
One of the tables database structure is similar to this

```
'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS '._DB_PREFIX_.'MODULE_ITEM
(
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `active` VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE='._MYSQL_ENGINE_.' DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;'
```

So, the list_fields value is like this

```
array(
 'id' => array(
   title' => $this->l('Id'),
   //'width' => 140,
   'type' => 'text',
   'align' => 'center'
  ),
 'name' => array(
   'title' => $this->l('Name'),
   //'width' => 140,
   'type' => 'text',
   'align' => 'center'
  ),
'active' => array(
   'title' => $this->l('Status'),
    //'width' => 140,
   'active' => 'statusItem',
   'type' => 'boolean',
   'align' => 'center',
   'ajax'=> true
  )
);
```

As I intend to enable or disable the item via a button I use the 'active' and 'ajax' options for this specific field, and when rendered in the module configuration page the link generated for the column in question is something like: `index.php?controller=AdminModules&amp;configure=Example&item_id=4&statusItem&action=statusItem&ajax=1&(...)`. Please notice that statusItem is the name of the action.

On the other hand, I wrote this function in the module main file, which should change the item status.

```
public function ajaxProcessStatusItem()
 {
    $id=(int)Tools::getValue('item_id');
    $value=(int) Db::getInstance()->executeS($this->createSelectQuery('module_item','item_id',$id))[active];
    Db::getInstance()->update('module_item', array('active' => !$value), 'item_id='.$id);
    die();
 }
```

I've been using [this](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Using+the+HelperList+class) article of the official documentation to create the list, but no matter what name I use ('ajaxProcess', 'ajaxProcessSatusItem', 'statusItem', and every caps variation I could think of)  all I get is a blank page in response, and no change in the status. I had a look at the source code and there is no comment in the HelperList class regarding how the function should be called.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use ObjectModel class for your data object, you can autmatically generate toggle button just by adding one line:

```
AdminProductTabController.php or when defining fields somwehre else
and calling HelperList->generate()

'active' => array(
    'title'      => 'Active',
    'active'     => 'status',
    'filter_key' => '!active',
    'type'       => 'bool',
    'width'      => 'auto',
    'orderby'    => false,
    'search'     => false,
)
```

Line `'active' => 'status',` doesn't refer to any field names. Add this line to your list definition (if you're defining list field properties in Admin{YourObjectModel}Controller or calling HelperList from somewhere else).

An excerpt from my ObjectModel:

```
ProductTab.php

class ProductTab extends ObjectModel {
.......
   public static $definition = array(
   ..........
   'active' => array('type' => self::TYPE_BOOL, 'validate' => 'isBool',),
```

I looked up my code and I noticed that I actually called a special processing function:

```
AdminProductTabController.php

public function initProcess()
{
    $id_product_tab = (int)Tools::getValue('id_product_tab');
    $product_tab = new ProductTab($id_product_tab);

    $isStatusAction   = Tools::getIsset('status'.$this->table);

    if ($isStatusAction)
    {
        $product_tab->toggleStatus();
        Tools::redirectAdmin($this->href_back);
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you out.

Comment: Does the 'active' field need to be a boolean? As an alternative I used a ajaxProcessStatusItem simmilar to the one showed in AdminStatusesController, but that didn't work either.